# Updating Chart with live Values, adding second line

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, highcharts, linechart

I am trying to add a second line to my chart but i cannot seem to get the line to add correctly. My first line gets new points using an ajax query and it adds fine. When i try add a second line to the same graph i does get added to the legend but it doesnt plot on my graph. 
Here is my code

```
var series = this.series[0];
                var series1 = this.series[1];
                setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://10.175.129.10/output_file.json', function(data) 
            {
            pp_time_offset_value =`${(data[0].pp_time_offset )}`
            var par = parseInt(pp_time_offset_value);

            time_offset_value =`${(data[0].time_offset )}`
            var par2 = parseInt(time_offset_value);

                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                     //y = par;#

                    <!-- y= Math.random() * (500 - 200) + 200 -->
                    series.addPoint([x, par,par2], true, true);
                    //series.addPoint([x, ], true, true);
                    console.log( par2);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },


    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'pp_time_offset',
        data: (function () {
            yyy=2;
            //yyy =`${(data[0].graph_value )}`
            // generate an aray of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -60; i <= 0; i ++) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 500,
                 //   y: Math.random() * (-15000 - 00) + 200
                });
            }
            return data;

        }())
    },
     {
        name: 'time offset',
          data: (function () {
            yyy=2;
            //yyy =`${(data[0].graph_value )}`
            // generate an aray of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -60; i <= 0; i ++) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 500,
                 //   y: Math.random() * (-15000 - 00) + 200
                });
            }
            return data;

        }())
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so problem solved, the issue was I was assigning the new line to the old data and overwriting it. Solution

```
                var series = this.series[0];
                var series1 = this.series[1];
                setInterval(function () {

                $.getJSON('http://10.175.129.10/output_file.json', function(data) 
            {
            pp_time_offset_value =`${(data[0].pp_time_offset )}`
            var par = parseInt(pp_time_offset_value);

            time_offset_value =`${(data[0].time_offset )}`
            var par2 = parseInt(time_offset_value);

                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                     //y = par;#

                    <!-- y= Math.random() * (500 - 200) + 200 -->
                    series.addPoint([x, par], true, true);
                    series1.addPoint([x,par2], true, true);
                    console.log( par2);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, please check your answer as accepted, so others can focus on the questions which still need an answer please.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried but i get an error message saying i cannot accept the answer for another 2 days.